# Handling acks in Akka Streams

Tags: architecture, akka, akka-stream

I have seen the examples of using Akka Streams to avoid backpressure but wondering how this works if I need to get custom `acks` downstream?

In my specific case I have several `flows` in the chain which process a message and when it reaches a certain `flow` I would like to pass an `ack` back to the source in order to signal that I have now "taken ownership" of the resource being processes.

How does this work in Akka Streams?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is more than one solution to this problem. A simple approach is to augment your data with a `Promise[Unit]` to be successfully completed to signal an *ack*.
This has its cons (namely the lack of backpressure support), but it has simplicity by its side.

For more information on the topic, check out [this blogpost](http://tim.theenchanter.com/2015/07/the-need-for-acknowledgement-in-streams.html).

[Acked-stream](https://github.com/timcharper/acked-stream) is an excellent library based on this approach.